# Non-floated div drops below right floated div in IE9 (and 7)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

This is a responsive site, (http://www.dermatologypartners.com) with desktop styles first. IE8 handles the pages correctly, though without CSS3 flourishes. But IE9 is dropping my navbar (on left) down, when it is up next to the right floated content in all the other browsers.

My navbar is near the end of the HTML because I want it to flow over LAST, below page content but above the footer, in the smartphone version of the site -- which it does.

The nav is NOT floated. It just rises to the top left and content is floated to the right.

Except in IE9.

I don't to have to redo all this, if I can just get an IE9 fix. It's not "float drop" - there's plenty of room available. I'm actually having the same problem in IE7, but I'm not concerned with IE7 -- but why 7 & 9, while 8 is fine?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Though without CSS3 flourishes"* - [are you sure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flourish)?

Comment: Well, in IE8 there's no border-radius's  - rounded boxes are all squares. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

To you .gradient div, add `width:19%`, and on your #nav div, change width to 100%.

Comment: Thank You for responding. If I make my #nav 100% it stretches in all the other browsers. I put up a temporary ie9 only stylesheet so if you visit the site now it's got a fixed width and looks decent. But if you look at ie7, that's what 9 was doing.